# Storing the value in last index object of nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am creating a bunch of buttons in a UIView dynamically. I added all the button frames and tag in a NSMutable array. I have a word like "escape" from which i am extracting each character and store in a UIButton randomly with the help of tag. But the problem is it is displaying only the last alphabet and store only in one button.
Please help me.

This is my code

```
   -(void)createButtonFrame
{
    for (float colCount=1;colCount<222.6;) {
        for (float rowCount=1;rowCount<=450;) {
            alphabetButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rowCount-1,colCount-1,50,27.4)];

            alphabetButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
                alphabetButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.8f;
            alphabetButton.tag=tagButtonValue;

            [masterView addSubview:alphabetButton];
            [btnArray addObject:alphabetButton];
             rowCount+=50;
            tagButtonValue++;
        }
        colCount+=27.4;
    }
```

}

```
-(void)puAlphabetFunction
{


    for (int wordCount=0;wordCount<[alphabetArray count]; wordCount++) {
        word=[alphabetArray objectAtIndex:wordCount];
        [self putrandomAlphabet:word];

    }
}

-(void)putrandomAlphabet:(NSString*)wordString
{


   for (int characterCount=0;characterCount<wordString.length;characterCount++) {
       retreiveCharacter = [wordString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(characterCount, 1)];
       srandom( time( NULL ) );
       int  randomNumber = (random() % [btnArray count]);
 btnvalue=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:randomNumber+1];
       if (firstTime==0) {
           lastIndex=randomNumber;
           [btnvalue setTitle:retreiveCharacter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           firstTime++;

       }
       else
       {

             [btnvalue setTitle:retreiveCharacter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }
       [btnvalue setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnvalue.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue"     size:17.0]];


    }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried... can you show some code?

Comment: Please check my code.

Comment: try with...[[btnArray addObject:alphabetButton]retain]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use randon() function. Use arc4random() instead. It will generate random numbers in normalised way.